# Gradle does not execute any tests on commandline

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, junit5, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My Gradle project is using KotlinDSL and JUnit5 / Jupiter (and Kotlin as a programming language), Gradle does not seem to pick up any of my tests properly. When I run Gradle test on the command line, it tells me

```
SUCCESS: Executed 0 tests in 1s
```

no matter what I try. However, in my IDE, I can easily run every single test class in my project without any problems.

My buildfile build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.8.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    id("com.adarshr.test-logger") version "1.7.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "myprojectgroup"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


val junitVersion="5.5.2"
val mockitoVersion="2.28.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion")
    testCompile ("org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:$mockitoVersion")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines("junit-jupiter")
    }
}
```

The test classes live under src/test/kotlin as expected, test methods are annotated with the correct org.junit.jupiter.api.Test annotation. Any ideas what I could try? It really starts driving me mad.

Thanks a lot, folks!

Konstantin

Comment: May you want to compare your project with the gradle example project:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/userguide/organizingGradleProjects/separatedTestTypes/kotlin

Comment: Thanks for the hint! However the project you mentioned uses Java instead of Kotlin as programming language and JUnit 4.x instead of 5.x so to me it does not look as if that helps me. The usual examples with this stack works for me as well.

Comment: There are a lot of different languages available. Here the top link: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/userguide

Answer (score 0):

```
tasks.test { scanForTestClasses = true useJUnitPlatform { includeEngines("junit-jupiter") } }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 